# How to get a normalized, grouped, ordered plot of counts

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

How can I get in seaborn a chart of counts, per category, normalized, in a specified order?

It seems like I could either do countplot like this:

```
sns.countplot(data=df, y="category_1",hue='category_2', 
    order = df['category_1'].value_counts().iloc[:10].index)
```

Which gives me the counts, but countplot doesn't seem to have an argument to normalize the counts to percentages:

[image]

Looks like histplot would have the option `stat = 'probability'`, which would normalize the data as I would need, but then it doesn't have the order argument.

How can I get normalized occurrence count charts per category, in order?

Answer (score 0):

You can first `groupby` whatever you want to normalize.

For example,

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

df_g = df \
    .groupby('origin')['cylinders'] \
    .value_counts(normalize=True) \
    .rename('prop') \
    .reset_index()
```

then you can use `sns.barplot`

```
sns.barplot(data=df_g, 
            x='prop', y='origin',
            hue='cylinders',
            order = df['origin'].value_counts().index)
```

In this case you should use the original dataframe, and not the grouped version. So, if you don't want to create a new variable, just pass `data=df.groupby...` to `barplot`.